# How do I delete this '# ... #' Emacs File?

Tags: macos, unix, emacs, delete-file

There is a file in my home directory that is called #snake#. I want to remove it but none of the regular remove commands will work. How can this "file" be removed without causing any damage, and what type of file is it?

Comment: Have you considered `rm`?  And if you type `file #snake#` you can see what type it is I think, I am not sure for OSX.

Answer (score 5):

It's an autosave file, it's there in case your computer crashes. You can delete these from emacs quite conveniently. Open up dired (C-x d) and press `#` to select all of them in the directory. Then `x` for delete.

Alternatively in a shell, just put the name in quotes, e.g. `rm "#snake#"`

Answer (score 4):

The "problem" is that the `#` sign is interpreted as the start of a comment in a shell. Try enclose the file name in quotes, like:

```
rm "#snake#"
```